# Simulating rails controller using CURL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I want to simulate several function in my rails application by using curl in terminal. The problem I am facing now is that first I login in my application using user name and password. But then while I am hitting the url corresponding to a function of a controller, it is giving message **"You are redirected to sign_in page"**.

I think I have to use authenticity token somehow. But I don't know how to get it and how to pass it during each call to controller function. So if anyone helps me to figure it out, I will be really grateful.

Comment: You need to authenticate, then capture, the auth cookie and send it with your request. Maybe cURL’s `cookie-jar` option can help: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the format of the request modify the controller code to handle both the html and json request separately.

In the first request get the access token in response from your controller. You can use this authentication token for your further request.

In order you generate the access token

> > - Create a migration in users table for authentication token
> > - When the user logins/sign-up create the authentication token for that user

Once you make these changes you can have the user information passed using the curl request and pass back the authentication token in response for the user.
For further request use this authentication token to verify the user and perform the actions.